# Json Decode Error, resolved only when copy pasting to new txt file and resaving as json

Tags: python, json

I have pulled JSON files from an API using the command line. I am hit with decode errors when attempting to load the file using the JSON module. As far as I can tell the files are definitely JSON.

When I copy paste the JSON file to a new text file and save it as a JSON file, I can parse the file no problem. I would like to avoid manually copy, pasting, resaving all these files every time i need to run my script.

Sample of Json:

```
{
    "ReservedDBInstancesOfferings": [
        {
            "MultiAZ": true, 
            "OfferingType": "Partial Upfront", 
            "FixedPrice": 280.0, 
            "UsagePrice": 0.0, 
            "ReservedDBInstancesOfferingId": "001b899a-be28-489b-9a71-4ff7406d2107", 
            "RecurringCharges": [
                {
                    "RecurringChargeAmount": 0.032, 
                    "RecurringChargeFrequency": "Hourly"
                }
            ], 
            "ProductDescription": "sqlserver-se(byol)", 
            "Duration": 31536000, 
            "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.small", 
            "CurrencyCode": "USD"
        },
```

How i am opening:

```
 with open('C:\\Users\\xxx\\PycharmProjects\\Pricing_File\\CLI Files\\'+inputFile+'-cli.json', 'r') as f:
        rawData = json.load(f)
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Pricing_File/RDS_CLI_JSON_parse_script.py", line 4, in <module>
        data = json.load(f)
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

As a reminder, I literally copy paste the json file into a new file and it works.
```

Comment: The error clearly indicates the line number and character position in the stream. What *OS* are you on? I suspect an *EOLN* mismatch.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise 2016.

    in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Please add the *json*, full traceback and code that throws the exception, as described in [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), *Python* version. *EOLN* stands for *end of line*. Although *json* module should be proof to such mismatches, you might have *Ux* style line terminators in your file (or might be other "invisible" chars)?

Comment: updated the original post.

Comment: How do you open `f`? Are you using binary mode?

Comment: i am using with open. updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. Most likely, the original file is saved in *Unicode* - also referred to as [[Wikipedia]: Wide character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) (`wchar_t` - check [[MSDN]: Working with Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details) in *Win* world.

To demonstrate, I created 3 files containing the *json* below, but each having something different:

```
{
    "dummy": 0
}
```

- *ux.jsn* - *Ux* style *eoln* (`\n` or *0x0A*)
- *win.jsn* - *Win* style *eoln* (`\r\n` or *0x0D 0x0A*)
- *uc.jsn* - The **Wide character** format that I talked about (the *eoln*s are *Win* style, but that's irrelevant)

Then, some code that for each one of the files:

- Opens it in *binary* (or *raw*) mode, gets its content and displays it (using [[Python]: **repr**(*object*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)) on screen
- Opens it in normal mode and tries to load its *json* content (and display it on screen as well)

*code.py*:

```
import json


FILE_NAMES = [
    "ux.jsn",
    "win.jsn",
    "uc.jsn",
]


def main():
    for file_name in FILE_NAMES:
        print("\n{}:".format(file_name))
        with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
            raw_content = f.read()
            print("    Size: {} - [{}]".format(len(raw_content), repr(raw_content)))
        with open(file_name, "r") as f:
            print("    {}".format(json.load(f)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output** (running *Python3.6.2x86* on *W10x64*):

> ```
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q48194775>"c:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\python.exe" code.py
>
> ux.jsn:
>     Size: 19 - [b'{\n    "dummy": 0\n}\n']
>     {'dummy': 0}
>
> win.jsn:
>     Size: 22 - [b'{\r\n    "dummy": 0\r\n}\r\n']
>     {'dummy': 0}
>
> uc.jsn:
>     Size: 44 - [b'{\x00\r\x00\n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00"\x00d\x00u\x00m\x00m\x00y\x00"\x00:\x00 \x000\x00\r\x00\n\x00}\x00\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00\n\x00']
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code.py", line 23, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "code.py", line 19, in main
>     print("    {}".format(json.load(f)))
>   File "c:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
>     parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>   File "c:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
>     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>   File "c:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>   File "c:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
>     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
> ```

**Conclusions**:

- Although they apparently have the same content, it's not the case. The faulty file has twice the size, that is because each character is represented on 2 bytes (and since they are all regular *ASCII* characters, the 1<sup>st</sup> byte is `\0` or *0x00*)
- For some reason, *json* does not like that and throws an error when trying to parse the content (although the errors are a little bit different)
- When you copy/paste the file, *Win* automatically converts it to a *normal* format and therefore *json* is able to parse it afterwards

As a fix, I converted it using a dummy method (note that if the *json* content may contain legitimate `\0`s, they **will be removed as well**), although I'm sure there are tools that do this properly:

> ```
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q48194775>"c:\Install\x86\Python\Python\3.6\python.exe"
> Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> with open("uc.jsn", "rb") as f:
> ...     raw_content = f.read()
> ...
> >>> with open("uc0.jsn", "wb") as f:
> ...     f.write(raw_content.replace(b"\0", b""))
> ...
> 22
> >>> import json
> >>> with open("uc0.jsn", "r") as f:
> ...     print("    {}".format(json.load(f)))
> ...
>     {'dummy': 0}
> >>> with open("uc.jsn", "r") as f:
> ...     print("    {}".format(json.load(f)))
> ...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> # The rest of the traceback
> ```